# How to set Title for UITabBarItem without changing tint color

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

When I change the title of a `UITabBarItem` in a `UITabBar` programmatically from a `UIViewController` in another tab, the title changes correctly, but the image of the `UITabBarItem` changes its color to the `tintColor` or the tabbar.

Here is what is looks like after I set the title of the third tab within the UIViewController of the second tab like this

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![2].title = "9 Places"
```

[image: After setting the title for the third tab]

Any idea how I can prevent the third tab icon from changing the tint color?

**Using Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12.1.1.**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more code? e.g. how you set `tabBar.tintColor`.

Comment: I am setting the tintColor generally with this         
`UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = App.Constant.keyColor` and `UIView.appearance().tintColor = App.Constant.keyColor`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be better off setting the title and the image together.

```
self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "9 Places", image: yourImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: yourImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Gallo Torres Sevilla did not work for me, but it did point me in the right direction. So thanks for this.

Basically when setting up the `UITabBarItem` for the first time, I needed to supply the image including the `renderingMode` as suggested by Gallo as well as the `selectedImage`. Then subsequent changes to the `title` do not impact the tint.